# HTML controls not working under <td> tag in ASP.NET page

Tags: html, asp.net, runtime-error

I am working to get a HTML File Upload control in place in a ASPX Web Form page. I have used the below code

```
   <td class="ClientDetailTableLeftColumn">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload File"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td "ClientDetailTableControls" colspan="2">

                    <p id="UploadArea">
                    <input id="FileUploadInput" type="file" size="20"/>
                     <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Click To Upload" CssClass="btnFormSubmit" />
                    </p>
                        <input id="btnUploadMore" type="button" value="Add New Attachment" onclick="AddUploadBox" />
                </td>
```

But while running in Local IIS I am getting an error.

> System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCellCollection must have items of
>   type System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell'. 'p' is of type
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'.

The code is failing in the 2nd Line :

```
Line 85:                 <td "ClientDetailTableControls" colspan="2">

Line 86:                     <p id="UploadArea">
```

Can somebody please help me what could be the resolution to this? Or why is this failing?

Comment: instead of <p> use <div>

Comment: Thanks the P<Tag> and the class with <TD> wasn't working. Now I got it going.

Comment: did you make the change what i said??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td class="ClientDetailTableLeftColumn">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload File"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td "ClientDetailTableControls" colspan="2">

                    <div id="UploadArea">
                    <input id="FileUploadInput" type="file" size="20"/>
                     <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Click To Upload" CssClass="btnFormSubmit" />
                    </div>
                        <input id="btnUploadMore" type="button" value="Add New Attachment" onclick="AddUploadBox" />
                </td>
```